# Change color type of bitmap in SkiaSharp?

Tags: skiasharp, skia

I have a bunch of gifs I want to create thumbnails for using SkiaSharp. But `SKBitmap.Resize` method returns null when having a source bitmap with color type other than 32-bit (as it seems). But how do I change the source bitmap to 32-bit colors? (from Index8)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?